# В юнити скрипт без ошибок, а он не работает

Tags: unity3d

Тут ошибка

```
private void OntriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Score")
    {
        score++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Теперь подождём экстрасенсов, которые будут угадывать весь текст ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, какая у Вас ошибка (на будущее: прикрепляйте вместе с кодом данные об ошибке), но меня смущает то, что Вы вместо `OnTriggerEnter2D` написали `OntriggerEnter2D`, т.е. написали `trigger` с маленькой буквы. Может быть, в этом заключается ошибка?

Comment: Брат от души , спосибо!